Missing add configuration transform in Visual Studio 2022
I am using Visual Studio 2022 and have a few projects with transforms for various configurations that I generated using Visual Studio 2019.
Now that I have ported those projects to VS 2022, I am missing the "Add Configuration" transform from the context menu of the project(s), even though I have all the configurations defined. All I see are debug and release.
Please help!
Thanks
I have tried running VS 2022 in admin mode, I have tried to manually create them and modify the Project file, but the build and publish options won't recognize them

Could you share more detail about your project?only web config transforms only applys to web applications instead of website projects,and some configuration files would be appreciated.
